# Return random value for each row from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get random name for each row, but it just shows same random value for every row. What am I missing?

```
SELECT TOP (1000)  v.id,v.[Name], RandomName 
FROM [V3_Priva].[dbo].[Vehicle] v
cross join
(Select top 1 ISNULL([Description_cs-CZ], [Description]) RandomName
from crm.Enumeration e
join crm.EnumerationType et on e.EnumerationType_FK = et.Id
where  EnumerationType_FK = 12
order by NEWID()) RandomName
```

[Result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVqct.png)

Comment: Because the subquery is run once, not once per row. You could move it to the `SELECT` but doing something like this is expensive.

Comment: @Larnu Basically boils down to undocumented idiosyncrasies with `NEWID()`, it's only guaranteed to be recalculated if used directly in the outermost `SELECT`

Comment: I *suspect* that if the subquery were correlated, it would be different, @Charlieface , and it would be run once per value of what ever the correlated value was. So, if that were the PK of `Vehicle` once per row.

Comment: @Larnu Possibly, although I have run into some weird edge cases with this before. It all comes down to the shape of the query plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something like the following to drive your lookup.

```
DECLARE @Rows AS TABLE ( I INT NOT NULL )

DECLARE @Vals AS TABLE ( ID INT IDENTITY, Val NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL )

INSERT INTO @Rows
VALUES ( 0 )
,      ( 1 )
,      ( 2 )
,      ( 3 )
,      ( 4 )
,      ( 5 )
,      ( 6 )
,      ( 7 )
,      ( 8 )
,      ( 9 )

INSERT INTO @Vals
VALUES ( 'Apple' )
,      ( 'Banana' )
,      ( 'Peach' )
,      ( 'Plum' )
,      ( 'Pear' )

WITH cte AS ( SELECT    *, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5 ID FROM  @Rows )
SELECT  cte.I
,       cte.ID
,       V.ID
,       V.Val
  FROM  cte
  JOIN  @Vals V ON V.ID = cte.ID  + 1
 ORDER BY I
```

This way new ID is generated for each row, rather than once for the lookup.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your answer inspired me to use temp tables and helped me to figure out solution